# Why is this function generate $a_n = 2^n(n+1)$?

Tags: calculus, generating-functions

Let $G(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ which generates the sequence $a_n = n+1$
How can one infer that $G(2x) = \frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}$ generates $a_n = 2^n(n+1)$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)t^n.$$

Replace $t$ everywhere by $2x$. Since $(2x)^n=2^n x^n$, the coefficient of $x^n$ is $(n+1)2^n$.

Comment: You are welcome. After one has a basic stock of generating functions, "new" ones are often obtained by manipulation of old ones. The manipulation tools include substitution (as in this case), addition, multiplication, formal differentiation, formal integration, and others.

Comment: Thank you for this note. Something prevented me to try it myself for some reason. I need to have more confidence.